# Android: Storing value for application lifetime and/or application termination

Tags: android, android-activity, exit

I want to store a value when my application is first executed and that value should remain until the application is terminated (by some sort of task manager) or the application chooses to exit itself. I want the value to persist after the application has been in the background and through screen rotates.

There is absolutely no reason for my application to stay running in the background once I decide to exit so terminating the application is an option. How do I do that as just ending the activity doesn't work?

Note that I am the ONLY user of the application so best practises can probably be thrown out the window.

Answer (score 2):

Use a static data member (a.k.a., singleton). That will live for the life of your process and will go away when the process does.

Comment: How can I ensure that it goes away when the process does? Currently I have a static data member in a class that extends Application. It persists even after exit (or what seems like exit).

Comment: You can end your Activity without exiting the Application.  Does your value persist when you go into Settings > Apps and kill the app?

Comment: Yes the value persists when I kill the app as it is now. If I end the activity it also persists (as it should).

Comment: @diolemo: "How can I ensure that it goes away when the process does?" -- it does by definition. "It persists even after exit" -- then your process is still around. Clearly, you have your own custom definition of "exit". You are welcome to set the singleton to `null` when whatever you consider "exit" occurs.

Comment: When I kill the process using the default task manager (or any other task manager on the market) I expect the value to no longer persist. This is not the case.

Comment: @diolemo: Use DDMS to terminate your process. If you still think your value is being retained, then your test is flawed (e.g., you are lazy-initializing the static data member, and therefore it is always around when you access it). You may also wish to spend some time learning about processes, as no memory survives a process termination on any modern operating system.

Comment: @CommonsWare The task manager must not actually be killing it. Force stop does work.

Answer (score 1):

There are answers in SO that tell you how to quit an application, as well as recommendations that you should not.  If you really don't care about best practices, you can make the app quit itself.

On the other hand, maybe it would be sufficient for your value to persist only through the lifetime of the Activity.  Try putting something like this in your Activity's `onCreate()` method:

```
if (savedInstanceState == null) {
    // Do initial setup
}
```